# How do I use coalesce rowise?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this tibble

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(first = c("a", NA, "b"),
           second = c(NA, "b", NA),
           third = c("a", NA, NA))
```

I would like to use `coalesce()` row-wise to grab only values that are not NA.

The desired output would be a vector of the first non NA values that we can find inspecting the dataframe rowwise from left to righ

```
[1] "a" "b" "b"
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `do.call` with `coalesce`:

```
do.call(coalesce, df)
# [1] "a" "b" "b"
```

`do.call` passes columns in `df` to `coalesce` in order and thus equivalent to `coalesce(df$first, df$second, df$third)`.

---

```
df <- data_frame(
    first = c("a", NA, "b"),
    second = c(NA, "b", NA),
    third = c("a", NA, NA)
)
```

Comment: @Onyambu when I asked the question, I meant by "rowwise" "between columns", while I would call the the normal behavior of coalesce "columnwise" namely "within a column"

Comment: Its okay. I guess I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Onyambu Good idea using the `!!!` operator, more `dplyr` than `do.call`.

Comment: But only used when we coalesce one column to another. Not one row to another. Even the `do.call` coalesces one column to another and not one row to another

Answer (score 0):

Using *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

fcoalesce(df)
# [1] "a" "b" "b"
```