# Row-wise coalesce over all columns

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce, rowwise

How can we get first non-missing value - *coalesce* - row-wise using *dplyr* (*tidyverse*) for all columns without specifying column names?

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "s3", NA, NA,"s4"),
                 y = c("s1", NA, "s6", "s7", "s4"),
                 z = c("s1", NA, NA, "s7", NA))
```

We could use [*do.call*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48711056/680068), but this does not look tidy-like:

```
df$xyz <- do.call(coalesce, df)
#      x    y    z xyz
# 1 <NA>   s1   s1  s1
# 2   s3 <NA> <NA>  s3
# 3 <NA>   s6 <NA>  s6
# 4 <NA>   s7   s7  s7
# 5   s4   s4 <NA>  s4
```

This works, but I don't want to specify columns:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(xyz = coalesce(x, y, z))
#      x    y    z xyz
# 1 <NA>   s1   s1  s1
# 2   s3 <NA> <NA>  s3
# 3 <NA>   s6 <NA>  s6
# 4 <NA>   s7   s7  s7
# 5   s4   s4 <NA>  s4
```

Similar to *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, xyz := fcoalesce(.SD) ][]
#       x    y    z xyz
# 1: <NA>   s1   s1  s1
# 2:   s3 <NA> <NA>  s3
# 3: <NA>   s6 <NA>  s6
# 4: <NA>   s7   s7  s7
# 5:   s4   s4 <NA>  s4
```

Failed attempts:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(xyz = coalesce(all_vars()))

df %>% 
  mutate(xyz = coalesce(c_across(all_vars())))

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(xyz = coalesce(all_vars()))

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(xyz = coalesce(c_across(all_vars())))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/tidyverse/funs/issues/54

Answer (score 6):

Taken from this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/funs/issues/54), you can create a `coacross` function:

```r
coacross <- function(...) {
  coalesce(!!!across(...))
}

df %>% 
  mutate(xyz = coacross(everything()))

     x    y    z xyz
1 <NA>   s1   s1  s1
2   s3 <NA> <NA>  s3
3 <NA>   s6 <NA>  s6
4 <NA>   s7   s7  s7
5   s4   s4 <NA>  s4
```

Comment: If one day `coacross` becomes part of the package, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can inject the data frame to `coalesce` using the splice operator `!!!`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(xyz = coalesce(!!!df))
```

Or more "tidyverse" like:

```
df %>% mutate(xyz = coalesce(!!!select(., everything())))
```

#### Output

```
     x    y    z xyz
1 <NA>   s1   s1  s1
2   s3 <NA> <NA>  s3
3 <NA>   s6 <NA>  s6
4 <NA>   s7   s7  s7
5   s4   s4 <NA>  s4
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, I don't want to call the dataframe within mutate.

Comment: This works fine on a defined dataframe, but when I incorporate in a function I get error in `coalesce()`: ! `...` can't be empty. :-(

Answer (score 2):

This is apossible solution:

```r
df %>%
    mutate(xyz = do.call(coalesce,across()))

#>     x    y    z xyz
#> 1 <NA>   s1   s1  s1
#> 2   s3 <NA> <NA>  s3
#> 3 <NA>   s6 <NA>  s6
#> 4 <NA>   s7   s7  s7
#> 5   s4   s4 <NA>  s4
```

Comment: It is much cleaner without *mutate*: `df$xyz <- do.call(coalesce, df)`

Comment: Probably, but my solution avoids to refer specifically to `df` allowing to apply it later in a data transformation chain.